# MVC 5 date model binding

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I recently upgraded a MVC 3 application to MVC 5. I created a new MVC 5 project and brought my files inside.
It seems that dates are being treated differently than before. There is an error validation message that shows on view by using `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x=>x.mydate)` that I can not override by DataAnnotation techniques or even use my previous model binder that uses a different culture for format "dd/MM/yyyy".
Could some one help to reveal me the changes for date validation in MVC 5?

My class annotation

```
public class passport
{

    [Display(Name = "Fecha de Solicitud")]
    //[DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? spanishfechaSolicitud { get; set; }
}
```

and the view.
before

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.passaporte.spanishfechaSolicitud, new { @Value = String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", Model.passaporte.spanishfechaSolicitud) })
```

after

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.passaporte.spanishfechaSolicitud)
```

I updated my code according to what i was advised. Remove DataType Attribute and the value html attribute. I also used the EditorFor(). Now the date is displaying fine on the page; however, the javascript validation is saying "The field Fecha de Solicitud must be a date." If I type it as MM/dd/yyyy it like it. How can I validate with this formatting? dd/MM/yyyy. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your DataAnnotations and the relevant HTML on your View?

Comment: To generate the textbox, use the [TextBoxFor() overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833694(v=vs.118).aspx) that accepts a format string `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.passaporte.spanishfechaSolicitud, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")` (don't try to override the `value` attribute). Have you included jquery `globalize.js`?

Answer (score 0):

MVC only formats dates using DisplayFormat when using `Html.EditorFor()` or `Html.DisplayFor()`.  `TextBoxFor()` will not use the attributes.

Additionally, it's incorrect to use the @ symbol in your attributes unless the attribute is a c# reserved word (such as @class).  Value is not a reserved word so no @ is required.

You also should not override the value like that, you're basically making the entire model binding pointless.

Comment: I did use 'Html.EditorFor()' but i got the same result; the format "dd/MM/yyyy" will not show on display.

Comment: @ManuelValle - if you remove the DataType attribute it will, this is conflicting with your DisplayFormat

Answer (score 0):

After looking around for a solution to the jquery validation error. I found this code which solved my problem on the client. I already had the validation on the server and that is working. I am sharing my finding here.

```
 $.validator.addMethod('date',
function (value, element) {
    if (this.optional(element)) {
        return true;
    }
    var ok = true;
    try {
        $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', value);
    }
    catch (err) {
        ok = false;
    }
    return ok;
});
```